# How can I sort the result of an observable in a multiple way?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a TableData type obserable which returns me a set of table rows and columns.
The user can select from the select a set of columns (to which the rows refer) to be sorted (by default in ascending order).
For example, if the user enters "employee" and "project", I should sort the lines first by employee, and in turn sort the projects in ascending order for each employee.

class type:

```
export interface TableColumn {
  value: string;
  label: string;
  hidden: boolean;
  format: (value: any) => string;
}

export interface TableRow {
  [key: string]: any;
}

export interface TableData {
  columns: TableColumn[];
  rows: TableRow[];
}
export class Activity {
  id?: number;
  [HOURS_KEY]: number;
  [DATE_KEY]: string;
  [EMPLOYEE_KEY]: ActivityEmployee;
  [TYPE_KEY]: ActivityType;
  [PROJECT_KEY]?: ActivityProject;
}

export class ActivityEmployee {
  id: number;
  lastName: string;
  firstName: string;
}
```

Assuming that now I wanted to sort by Employee and Project only (so a static example), how can I order in a chained way the obserables I get?

i call obserable result in this way:

```
tableDataColumns$ = this.activityCollection.groupedEntities$?.pipe(
    map((e) => e.columns)
  );
  tableDataRows$ = this.activityCollection.groupedEntities$?.pipe(
    map((e) => e.rows)
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sortBy = new Subject<[string, string]>();

tableDataRows$ = this.sortBy.pipe(
  startWith(["", ""]),
  switchMap(([sort1, sort2]) =>
    this.activityCollection.groupedEntities$.pipe(
      map(({ rows }) => rows),
      map(rows =>
        !!sort1 ? rows.sort((a, b) => (a[sort1] < b[sort1] ? -1 : 1)) : rows
      ),
      map(rows => (!!sort2 ? this.splitSortRows(rows, sort1, sort2) : rows))
    )
  )
);

splitSortRows = <T>(rows: T[], splitBy: string, sortBy: string): T[] => {
  const uniqueValues = [...new Set(rows.map(row => row[splitBy]))];
  const splitArray = uniqueValues.map(value =>
    rows.filter(row => row[splitBy] === value)
  );
  return splitArray.reduce(
    (acc, arrSegment) => [
      ...acc,
      ...arrSegment.sort((a, b) => a[sortBy] < b[sortBy] ? -1 : 1),
    ],
    [] as T[]
  );
};
```

We start by declaring a subject which will emit a tuple representing the two labels to sort by. We then setup our pipe with the following sequence:

1. Subscribe to our subject to receive the latest sorting criteria
2. Switch map to our source data observable.
3. Use `map()` with object deconstruction to get our `rows` data.
4. Sort the `rows` array based on our first criteria, done with a simple `.sort()`.
5. Next we invoke a more complex function to accomplish the sub-sorting.

As for how `splitSortRows()` works:

1. Create an array of unique row values of the first sort criteria.
2. For each unique item, we break our single array into multiple arrays. Each sub-array group shares the same value of our first filter criteria.
3. Next, we sort each sub-array then concat them back into a single array.

---

Now when your user clicks on one or two labels to sort by, you can emit those sorting labels in the `sortBy` subject. The subscription will take care of the rest.

```
this.sortBy.next(['employee', 'project']);
// tableDataRows$ should now emit a new array of rows sorted by employee first, and projects second
```

Comment: thanks, but i have 5 columns(not all are number, some are string), so this approac its too expansive maybe

Comment: Sorry about that @Man24. I updated my answer so it will sort both numbers and strings.